# How to set text size for app in one place?

Tags: android

I want to be able to set the text size on an application wide basis.
So I will need to be able to access the value in code and xml.

I tried putting the size in my dimens.xml as follows...

```
 <item name="text_size_small" type="dimen" format="float">15.0</item>
```

But I was unable to re-use this in xml i.e...

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
```

Gives an exception...

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class RadioButton
```

Also I think I would need to specify the units i.e 'sp' in this case.

So is there a way to do it?

If not, i will probably have to set all text size's that need setting, programmatically.
Hopefully someone knows a better way.

Answer (score 1):

inside `dimens.xml`, you can use the `<dimen` item, and specify the unit:

```
<dimen name="text_size_small">15sp</dimen>
```

to access it programmatically, you

```
textview.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_small), TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX);
```

in dimens the size is already scaled for the unit, so you don't need to apply the conversion again, hence the `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`

Comment: Thanks for that BB. Only thing is i need to access the value in code as well.
I dont seem to be able to do both.

Comment: Excellent answer, works a treat.
I think "TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX" is the vital bit I was missing.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your dimens.xml specify your like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size_small">15sp</dimen>
</resources>

In your layout use this
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"

If you want to set this programtically, try like this
textview.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_small));
```

Comment: Gave that a try, and the xml usage works fine.
But in code i get the value 60.449997. I think the 'sp' is confusing the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You must define own textview style.

@styles

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/CMTextView</item

</style>

<style name="CMTextView" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">

    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>

</style>
```

@dimens

```
<dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
```